# Twilio TaskRouter: How to match worker based on activity

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

In a routing step I would like to only match a task to a worker if that worker is in a specific activity; I've created a custom activity called 'outbound'. I've tried the following in the expressions

```
worker.activity == "outbound"
```

and

```
worker.activity_name == "outbound"
```

both of these did not work; is this possible to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When matching against worker attributes within a [TaskRouter expression](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/workflow-configuration) you can only match against keys in the [worker's `attributes` JSON object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/worker#worker-properties).

If you have a set of workers that is meant for outbound work and a different set that work on inbound work then I would keep the standard activities and add attributes to each worker to define their work. You can then direct calls in expressions using that attribute.